# Checking if there are enough memory to allocate my variable

Tags: python, memory, graph-theory

Say I have a very large graph G and I want to find the distance matrix which is just a two-dimensional array. Before I do that I want to make sure that there is enough memory to allocate my two-dimensional array. Raise memory error if there is no enough memory. I don't want to waste hours computing the distance matrix and finally getting a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to use numpy for this purpose. For sure numpy arrays will use less memory than standard lists, it is possible to control data type used for weights, there are lot of matrix operations implemented and if you try to allocate too large array you will get an exception.

```
>>> a = numpy.empty((100, 100))
>>> a = numpy.empty((100000000, 1000000000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Comment: Thanks. I would give that a try but I was a wonder if there is a way to do this in python without any other dependencies. Can we use for example C language allocators such as malloc?

Comment: No, as I know. Standard work is with containers (lists, dicts). Container can allocate its space (e.g. [None] * 1000, creates list with 1000 elements all set to None), but there is no guaranty how much memory it's elements will use. I think that numpy arrays are the closest to C that you will get with 'standard' libraries.